# Long text pushes button down in linearlayout

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to add some buttons programmatically. But for some reason long text pushes the entire button down in my linearlayout.

[image: problem]
This is the code I use to replicate this behaviour.

The button:

```
   public class MyButton : Button
    {
        public MyButton(Context ctx) : base(ctx)
        {
            SetTextColor(Color.White);
            SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 20);
            var llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 100, 1);
            llp.SetMargins(4, 0, 4, 4);
            LayoutParameters = llp;
            SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
        }
    }
```

The row: (I have two rows of buttons)

```
  public class MyRow : LinearLayout
    {
        public MyRow(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            if (LayoutParameters == null)
                LayoutParameters = GenerateDefaultLayoutParams();
            LayoutParameters.Height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
            LayoutParameters.Width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
            ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)LayoutParameters).Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
            ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)LayoutParameters).Weight = 0;
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        }
    }
```

The header:

```
 public class MyHeader : LinearLayout
    {
        public MyHeader(Context context, IAttributeSet set) : base(context, set)
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 0);
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
            Draw();
        }

        private void Draw()
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++)
            {
                var row = new MyRow(Context);
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    var btn = new MyButton(Context);
                    if (r == 0 && i == 0)
                        btn.Text = "long text long text  long text ";
                    else
                        btn.Text = $"Btn {r}.{i}";
                    row.AddView(btn);
                }
                AddView(row);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I add the header in xaml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <App1.Resources.layout.MyHeader
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myHeader1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As faar as I can see the content of the button should not move the position of the button. But it does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so apparently the LinearLayout works so that it layout its components based on the position of the the.. text (?) or the content of the component.

The text of all buttons is aligned in the picture. To fix this I added

```
SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical);
```

to the constructor of MyRow.

Answer (score 0):

On your buttons add

setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

Comment: I tried to add 
Ellipsize = Android.Text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.Marquee; 
for the buttons but unfortunately its still the same behaviour.